# How to get the values entered in Primefaces Filtered DataTable field and submit to stored procedure

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.1 with tomcat 7 and SQL Server for database. I have a stored procedure to query couple of attributes for a user.

I am trying to find out

1. To get filter filed value from primefaces data table.
2. Stop default ajax query, because it is hitting my DB for each character that I enter in filter field.
3. When I click on submit button, I have to get all these field values to all my stored procedure.

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE age >=? and income >=?
```

Backing bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {
private String firstName;
private int income;
private int age;
private int filter_income;
private int filter_age;
getter/setter ......
```

index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:dataTable id="userTable" value="#{userDAO.data}" var="ut" >
  <p:column headerText="First Name">
      <h:outputText value="#{ut.firstName}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Income" style="text-align:right;" width="120"
            filterBy="#{ut.income}"
            filterFunction="#{dataFilter.filterByIncome}"  binding="#{userBean.filter_income}" filterEvent="enter" >
            <h:outputText value="#{ut.income}">
                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

<p:column headerText="Age" style="text-align:right;" width="120"
            filterBy="#{ut.age}"
            filterFunction="#{dataFilter.filterByAge}"  binding="#{userBean.filter_age}" filterEvent="enter" >
            <h:outputText value="#{ut.age}" />
        </p:column>
```

- Created binding value for each column to get back the input text, didn't work.
- Tried to stop Ajax filterEvent="enter" didn't work.
- I am wondering what will be the best approach for submit button action listener.

Basically, I want to use my own filter method with stored procedure. By taking advantage of primefaces datatable.

Comment: Instead of trying to combine basic built in functionality, start using a lazyDataModel. It will give you all the control you need.

Comment: I'll definitely consider lazyDataModel if I can go more deep. So is that going to help me to get individual fields?

Comment: Individual filter fields?  Yes

Comment: Still I am not sure how can I stop ajax by overriding primefaces and query using submit button.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you mean

Comment: By default, primefaces filter querying the input with each keystroke. How can I stop this until I submit custom query request?